# Trying to make bot say what argument is missing for an error handler

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot say what argument was missing in an error handler in a cog file. I looked at the API and tried but i get the error, `File "/home/runner/Ultimate-Bot/cogs/Commands.py", line 35, in on_command_error missing_argument = error.missing_argument AttributeError: 'MissingRequiredArgument' object has no attribute 'missing_argument'`

Here is my code that I have,

```
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        missing_argument = error.missing_argument
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you forgot to type an important argument! `Missing Argument: {missing_argument}`")
```

**NOTE:** I am writing this in a cog file.

Comment: Why don't you just send the actual `error`? This will say which argument is missing

Comment: It was my error

Answer (score 2):

You can use `error.param.name`

Example:

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you forgot to type an important argument! `Missing Argument: {error.param.name}`")
```